# Vuejs Suggestion regarding component rendering

Tags: vue.js

Basically I have a component (profile comments) which has child components (friends, followers, Posts).

Initially I am loading the profile and passing the data through the props and fetching the data in their individual components.

I want to have a suggestion since I have a post component which has many posts as a v-for loop and i wanted to open its individual single post by its id (pk). Since the Post component is a child component of the profile component how can I replace the component with the Single post or should I dynamically render the component on the basic of the param?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit open ended on how you would proceed with it so you might get flagged.

However, here is a potential solution:

So your profile route might look something like this:

`/profile/:id`

```
<template>
  <Posts :posts="posts" />
  <Friends :friends="friends" />
  <Followers :followers="follower" />
</template>
```

As the posts get rendered out, you can click on one to show the post.

At which point you can probably add a new route in your `router/index.js` that takes the user to a whole new component that doesn't have the child/parent relationship.

```
{
  path: '/post/:id'
  component: () => import('../views/Post');
}
```

And once that route loads, you can fetch all of the post related data if you need it.

Alternatively, you can use child routes under your `/profile/:id` route, which in my opinion would be the more elegant solution.

Comment below if this didn't answer your question and I'll try to refine.

Comment: I tried that it worked though but i have a little problem with it, I have over 10 elements in the loop and when i trigger it every 10 times open at the same time, how can i limit it ?

Comment: Please add your new code in your question. I need to see what you are doing before I can answer you.